# Field required a single bean, but 2 were found

Tags: spring-boot

When trying to start up a Spring Boot `2.0.3` application with the `mvn clean spring-boot:run` command, I get the following error:

```
Field applicationProperties in com.thalasoft.user.rest.security.TokenAuthenticationServiceImpl required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - userProdProperties: defined in file [/home/stephane/dev/java/projects/user-rest/target/classes/com/thalasoft/user/rest/config/properties/UserProdProperties.class]
    - com.thalasoft.user.rest.config.properties.UserProdProperties: defined in file [/home/stephane/dev/java/projects/user-rest/target/classes/com/thalasoft/user/rest/config/properties/UserProdProperties.class]
```

But there is only one such `UserProdProperties` class:

```
@EnvProd
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:user-prod.properties" })
public class UserProdProperties extends AbstractUserProperties {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserProdProperties.class);

    public UserProdProperties() {
        logger.debug("Loading the Prod properties file");
    }

}
```

And the service class that uses the injected bean, has no constructor:

```
@Service
public class TokenAuthenticationServiceImpl implements TokenAuthenticationService {
    @Autowired
    private UserProperties applicationProperties;
}
```

My application is started with the following class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

The application configuration is done with the class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(nameGenerator = PackageBeanNameGenerator.class, basePackages = { "com.thalasoft.user.rest.config",
                "com.thalasoft.user.rest.service", "com.thalasoft.user.rest.bootstrap", "com.thalasoft.user.data" })
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
}
```

And the web configuration class uses the following annotations:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
@ComponentScan(nameGenerator = PackageBeanNameGenerator.class, basePackages = { "com.thalasoft.user.rest.exception",
        "com.thalasoft.user.rest.controller", "com.thalasoft.user.rest.assembler" })
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
}
```

UPDATE: I now noticed that the integration tests fail if a class having the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is present.
There is something with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.
If I have the a class annotated with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, then the integration tests also fail.
If I remove the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation from the `Application` class, then the integration tests run fine.

Comment: I suspect it's getting registered twice as it's annotated with `@Configuration` and also being referenced somewhere else by `@EnableConfigurationProperties`. I can't tell for sure as you haven't shared enough code.

Comment: I'm not explicitly using the `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation. It is not in my code base. But maybe it, or something equivalent, is being used by the `@SpringBootApplication` annoation which I'm using to start the application in production mode only. If I remove the `@Configuration` annotation from the `UserProdProperties` class then I logically get a property not found error, as no property bean is loaded. What else from the code base should I share ?

Comment: You should share the minimum that's necessary to reproduce the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for details.

Comment: Also, `UserProdProperties` isn't a configuration class. Configuration classes are used to define beans and typically have one or more `@Bean` methods. It should be annotated with `@Component` rather than `@Configuration`.

Comment: I replaced all `@Configuration` annotations in these property classes for `@Component` annotations. But the error remained identical.

Comment: When running the integration tests with the `mvn clean install -Denv="test" -Ddb="h2"` command, I make use of the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation so as to load the test properties. I suppose this annotation also loads the prod properties just as well, when running the application. Then, maybe the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation loads them again ? Can we suspect a conflict with these two annotations ?

Comment: Indeed, it's a conflict between the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` used by the integration tests and the `@SpringBootApplication` used in production.

Answer (score 0):

I could work around the issue by creating a configuration dedicated to the tests:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(nameGenerator = PackageBeanNameGenerator.class, basePackages = { "com.thalasoft.user.rest.config",
                "com.thalasoft.user.rest.service", "com.thalasoft.user.rest.bootstrap", "com.thalasoft.user.data" })
public class TestConfiguration {
}
```

And having the following configuration dedicated to the production:

```
@EnvProd
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}

@Component
@ComponentScan(nameGenerator = PackageBeanNameGenerator.class, basePackages = { "com.thalasoft.user.rest.properties", "com.thalasoft.user.rest.config",
                "com.thalasoft.user.rest.service", "com.thalasoft.user.rest.bootstrap", "com.thalasoft.user.data" })
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
}
```

Note the custom `@EnvProd` annotation that prevents the tests from seeing this class.